# The right way to run independent background process

Tags: .net-core, backgroundworker

I want this method to run, create background process, and exit. I don't want to `await` for the end of the asynchronous operation, I just want some process to be running in the background.

1. I tried using `Task.Run`, but when I try to debug the code inside it, breakpoint is never hit.
2. I thought, maybe Task.Run is only for operations that should be awaited, so I tried to use BackgroundWorker and put breakpoints in both places, `Task.Run` and `BackgroundWorker.DoWork`.
3. Now breakpoint inside Task.Run is hit twice, but breakpoint inside BackgroundWorker is skipped.

```
public override void Connect()
{
  // Uncomment code below and breakpoint inside Task.Run starts magically working :) 

  //var bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
  //bgw.DoWork += (_, __) => { Thread.Sleep(1000); };
  //bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += (_, __) => {};
  //bgw.RunWorkerAsync();

  Task.Run(() => {
    while (true) // Breakpoint here will NOT work
    {
      var x = 1; // Do something
    }
  });

  // Thread.Sleep(5000); // Uncommenting this also makes breakpoint working
}
```

**Question**

Why breakpoint inside async process is not being hit and what's the right way to create process that will kepp running even after completion of the method that created this process?

**Update**

It looks like the main process exits before Task is created, because if I add `Thread.Sleep(5000)` right after `Task.Run` it hits the breakpoint. Most probably, this is expected behavior to make sure that main process terminates all child threads before exiting.

Comment: Yes, if a process exits then your code stops running. Did you have another question?

Comment: @StephenCleary No, thanks, that is probably the only question. I just wanted to clarify if I really need to keep the main process alive in order to run some tasks created by it.

Comment: Yes, you do need to keep your process alive for it to run its code.